# How do I use 'plain' and 'pure'?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

Once I've been told that saying *'this code is pure C'* is incorrect, and I should use 'plain' instead of 'pure'.

Unfortunately, I can't see any difference. For example, how do I say something like this:

- 'You cannot solve this problem using *plain (?)* algebra. You have to use some geometry as well'
- '`@autoreleasepool` is not *plain (?)* C, it's Objective-C.'

I know there are some set phrases like 'This [idea] is *pure* genius' and in this case one can't replace 'pure' with 'plain'.

What about other cases? When to use 'plain' and when to use 'pure'?

Comment: "That program was developed purely on java" - This is a valid statement.

Comment: I doubt if *This code is pure C* (or C++, Java, JavaScript, or any other language) is really wrong.

Comment: @DamkerngT., I also think so. But if 'pure' is correct, when should I use 'plain' then?

Comment: You cannot solve this problem using algebra alone. You have to use (some) geometry as well.

Comment: @ForceBru In my opinion (keep in mind that I'm a non-native speaker), *This code is pure C* is an informal way to say *This code is written entirely in C* (i.e., no C++, no assembly, no other language is used in this code), while *This code is in plain C* makes me think that the code is mostly written in plain C, as opposed to C++, or any other way that could make the C code more sophisticated (like using macros or some other forms of preprocessing).

Comment: ["Written in pure C" looks like a pretty common phrase if you Google it.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22written%20in%20pure%20c%22)  I think whoever told you it was wrong was incorrect.

Comment: Pure C: written only in C (no AWK, sed...) . Plain C: written in entry-level C.

Answer (score 2):

**Plain** has the meaning without **embellishment** or **bells and whistles** or **additional features**
**Pure** has the meaning without **other ingredients**

> this code is **pure** C

is correct if the codebase is only in C and nothing else

**Plain C** is usually as specified by Kernighan and Ritchie, other flavours of C will depend on the compiler implementation, for example how **macros** are handled or **compile time variables** or **object handling**.

Another example would be orange juice:

> **Plain** orange juice can be thought of as the juice from [sweet oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(fruit)) and is the official orange juice of Florida.  **Fancier** orange juices may use **blood**, **valencia**, or **mandarin** oranges as their source.
>
> **Pure 100% orange juice** would be juice from only oranges without any additives and is sometimes referred to as **fresh squeezed** when appropriate.  [**Orange juice additives**](http://www.tropicana.com/products/tropicana_pure_premium) may include **calcium**, **omega-3**, **vitamin-D**, **anti-oxidants**, as well as **other fruit juices**. A popular addition to orange juice is **vodka** and the result is called a [**screwdriver**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screwdriver_(cocktail)).

For your algebra example

> **plain** algebra

may refer to what is more technically called **elementary algebra** also colloquially called **simple algebra** or **high school algebra** to make the distinction with

> **abstract** algebra
>   **polynomial** algebra
>   **linear** algebra
>   **non-linear** algebra

Comment: Well, I'd say "plain orange juice" means "orange juice that is not fancy". That could mean that you haven't added ingredients to liven it up -- added spices or alcohol or something -- in which case it could also be described as "pure". Or it could mean that it is orange juice made from ordinary oranges as opposed to special oranges grown at our high-tech farm or using our special patened fertilizer or whatever. "Pure" would mean containing real orange and nothing else, probably meaning we haven't added artifical flavors, or it is not contaminated with toxic chemicals.

Comment: @Jay +1 I;ve incorporated your thoughts in the answer

Answer (score 2):

What did you mean what you said the program is "pure C"?

"Pure" means this and nothing else, no contaminants or extra ingredients. "Plain" means ordinary.

So if your point was that the program is written with C and C alone, that there is no Java or Visual Basic or COBOL code in there, than your statement was perfectly correct and the normal way to express this idea.

If you meant that it used traditional C, K&R-ish, and not C# or C++, then I'd say "pure C" is not the correct term. "Plain C" would be more accurate, as you mean the ordinary, old, traditional C, and not the fancy new kinds of C like C#.